# How to remove comma if there is no next value

Tags: javascript

I am merging address values in one variable like -

```
obj.address1 = obj.address1 + ', ' + obj.city + ', ' + obj.state + ', ' + obj.zip_code
```

but if there is no value in **city/state/zip_code** comma is showing on UI, what can i do for remove this.

Comment: You can use regex to find two (or more) commas in a row and delete them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might not be the most elegant solution but you could add the comma only if defined using the ternary operator

```js
    const obj = {
      address1: "15th street",
      state: "NY",
      zip_code: 12345
    }
    obj.address1 = obj.address1 + ', ' + (obj.city ? obj.city + ', ' : '') + (obj.state ?   obj.state + ', ' : '') + obj.zip_code;
    console.log(obj.address1)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could create an array of all the address values and `filter` the empty values before `join`ing them with `,`

```js
const getAddress = o => [o.address1, o.city, o.state, o.zip_code]
                          .filter(Boolean)
                          .join(", ")

console.log(getAddress({ address1: '15th street', city: '', state: 'NY', zip_code: '12345' }))
console.log(getAddress({ city: 'Bengaluru', state: 'KA' }))
```

Answer (score 0):

After your line of code, you can just simply remove all commas that appears two (or more) in a row. Regex is the best for it. Here's an example:

```js
let abc = 'asd,,asd,asd'
abc = abc.replace(/\,{2,}/i, '')
```

Comment: You'll need to remove commas at the end and beginning of string too

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function merge(...params){
    let str = '';
    params.forEach((param)=> {if(param) str+= param + ', '});
    return str;
}

merge(obj.address1, obj.city, obj.state, obj.zip_code) // you can pass any number of arguments in this function
```

Answer (score 0):

little bit different approach

```
const obj = {
  address1: "address",
  state: "state name",
  city: "",
  zip_code: "zip"
}
const address = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]).filter(Boolean).join(", ");
console.log(address)
```